# Why are my camera keyframes so sharp?

Tags: camera, keyframes

[image: Why are they so sharp? I've tried clicking T and making it a bezier but the only one handle appears]

Why are they so sharp? I've tried typing <kbd>T</kbd> and making it a Bezier but the only one handle appears

Comment: Looks like you don't have ay keyframes after that one, so the F-curve generator is using "hold last value" interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example similar to yours:

[image: F Curve for camera motion]

On Frame 1, I set a location Keyframe.  On Frame 10, I moved the camera up on the Z axis and set another location Keyframe.  I'm only showing the Z curve.

Notice that I've manually rotated the handles for the Keyframe at frame 10 but that has no effect on the curve to the right of the keyframe.  Intuitively, that's because the camera has stopped moving.

Now I've moved to frame 15, moved the camera down, and added a keyframe.  I've also rotated the handles for that keyframe:

[image: New Keyframe at frame 15]

Now there's a smooth transition at frame 10, but a sharp one at frame 15.

The F Curve for location always shows the curve after the last keyframe as a flat line, because you've stopped moving the camera.